# how to tell convert.todatetime that the input is in format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

have written code that is supposed to

- take time and date input from the user
- and convert it to datetime format
- add some value to hrs and display it.

My code works fine when the user gives input in the default format but when the user enters a date like dd-mm-yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy(default), it doesn't work.

How can I change the convert function to take care of this?

```
    DateTime dt_calc = new DateTime();
    dt_calc = Convert.ToDateTime(inputt);
```

Answer (score 7):

To convert a date in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` use:

```
var dateValue = DateTime.Parse("11/03/1989", new CultureInfo("en-GB", false));
```

But don't forget to add the `System.Globalization` in the header or just do it inline:

```
var dateValue = DateTime.Parse("11/03/1989", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU", false));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Convert` - `DateTime` has [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx), `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` methods that take a `IFormatProvider` though for this simply using parse should work:

```
DateTime dt_calc = DateTime.Parse(inputt);
```

If you would rather be safe, use `TryParse:

```
DateTime dt_calc;
DateTime.TryParse(inputt, out dt_calc); // TryParse returns true if success, false if not
```

Comment: I guess you can try a number of known formats, and see which result in a valid entry. Only the 'ParseExact' methods take a format string however.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/date_time_parser_cs.aspx) that extends the DateTime parsing capabilities. Alternatively there's a [Natural Date Parser](http://gist.github.com/140483) class on GitHub.